# SQL ISO Standard for group concatenation

Tags: sql-standard, group-concatenation

Is there an operator in the latest standard SQL:2011 (or earlier) that will handle group concatenation the likes of which we currently have to resort to these tricks for?

- [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) in **MySQL**
- [FOR XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx) in **SQL Server**
- [LISTAGG in](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions089.htm#CJABDFBD) **Oracle**
- [string_agg](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) in **PostgreSQL**

Here's a [recent question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28659) on this site for which various answers were given to different RDBMS.

Since this is a small question for the heavyweight site DBA.SE, please find two sub-parts to the question:

1. Is there a publicly accessible draft of SQL:2011?
2. Which part of the SQL standard (any revision) states that CONCAT NULL should YIELD NULL? I can't seem to track it down in the volume of text in the standard.

Answer (score 4):

The wiscorp.com page **[SQL Standards](http://www.wiscorp.com/SQLStandards.html)** has several older revisions and [drafts of SQL:20nn](http://www.wiscorp.com/sql20nn.zip) (zip):

The **7IWD2-02-Foundation-2011-12.pdf**, with a date of **2011-12-21** has at page 289:

> If at least one of S1 and S2 is the null value, then the result of the `<concatenation>` is the null value.